# Change alert to input field

Tags: javascript

I have this code to get the file name when I'm browsing an image file.

```
document.getElementById('image').addEventListener('change',prepareUpload,false);

function prepareUpload(event)
{
  var files = event.target.files;
  var fileName = files[0].name;
  alert(fileName);
  filenames=document.watermark_url.filenames.value;
}
```

But the example code will prompt for the file name instead of displaying it in my input field. How to change the code so that when I upload an image, the file name will display in my input field?

Comment: `$('#inputid').val(fileName)`?

Comment: What is the name of your input field?

Comment: Could you provide us with a jsfiddle ?

Comment: @guradio.. it works.. thank you.. as simple as that..

Comment: @IamMoon glad it works happy coding mate.

Answer (score 0):

Change the alert to document.getElementById('inputtext.id').value = fileName;